# Error when using angular.copy() to copy data returned from ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
getContents: function ($scope, entityType, action, subjectId, contentTypeId, contentStatusId) {
                entityService.getContents(entityType, action, subjectId, contentTypeId, contentStatusId)
                .then(function (result) {
                    $scope.grid.data = result;
                    angular.copy($scope.grid.data, $scope.grid.originalData);
                    $scope.grid.newButtonEnabled = true;
                }, function (result) {
                    alert("Error: No data returned");
                    $scope.grid.newButtonEnabled = false;
                });
            },
```

and then the following function in entityService:

```
        getContents: function (entityType, action, subjectId, contentTypeId, contentStatusId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            EntityResource.getEntities({ entityType: entityType, subjectId: subjectId, contentTypeId: contentTypeId, contentStatusId: contentStatusId },
               function (resp) {
                   deferred.resolve(resp);
               }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

When I try to do an angular.copy I get a message saying:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
    at Object.copy (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:600:21)
    at factory.getContents.entityService.getContents.then.$scope.grid.newButtonEnabled (http://127.0.0.1:81/Content/app/admin/services/grid-service.js:303:29)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:7303:59)
    at ref.then (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:7340:26)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:8685:28)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:8548:23)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:8771:24)
    at done (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:10004:20)
    at completeRequest (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:10180:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:10144:11)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can make a copy of the data returned. Note that this data comes back from ngResource. Also this seems different from the other problems that I find on Stackoverflow related to: TypeError: Object # has no method 'push' questions.  With this problem I am getting the data back okay. It goes into $scope.grid.data but then gives me an error when trying to angular.copy the data.

Answer (score 9):

Take a close look at `angular.copy` [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy):

> destination(optional) – {(Object|Array)=} – Destination into which the source is copied. If provided, must be of the same type as source.

The result you got back from service call is probably an array; you however initialized `$scope.grid.originalData` as an object or something else other than array, so you got this type error.

Try to figure out what type the `result` is, and make `$scope.grid.originalData` the same type before calling `angular.copy`.